# Use scp to copy and duplicate file to remote host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I am using the following to copy a file to a remote host using `scp`, and then copy that file on the remote host to create an additional datestamped version:

```
scp myfile.tar.gz username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/root/myfolder
ssh username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx "cd /root/myfolder && cp myfile.tar.gz myfile_2020-06-23.tar.gz"
```

But is there a way of achieving this in a single step, without the additional remote copy (which takes some time, for a large file)?  I'm thinking something along the lines of what you can do when piping to `ssh` and using `cat - | tee` like follows:

```
... | ssh username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx "cat - | tee myfile.tar.gz > myfile_2020-06-23.tar.gz"
```

I guess another way of phrasing this question is... how can I pipe a `.tar.gz` file to the remote host over `ssh`?  That way, I can just pipe `myfile.tar.gz` to `ssh` and use the above trick to write simultaneously to two files, rather than using `scp` and then `cp`.

Comment: The easier solution is to `scp` the datestamped version and then have `myfile.tar.gz` just be a symlink to the latest.

Comment: You'd think so but symlinks complicate things a bit... mostly because when I browse to the remote folder over sftp (e.g. when out and about on my phone), I can't see any of the symlinks, so I can't tell if all is in order.  The host's default file browser also has problems with symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the remote server accepts typical unix commands, you can just do this:

```
cat myfile.tar.gz | ssh username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx \
        "cd /root/myfolder && tee myfile.tar.gz > myfile_2020-06-23.tar.gz"
```

Running `cat` on the remote server isn't necessary. Running `cat` on the local server isn't really necessary either--you could do this:

```
ssh username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx \
        "cd /root/myfolder && tee myfile.tar.gz > myfile_2020-06-23.tar.gz" \
        < myfile.tar.gz
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- Redirect from the file
```

You can even pipe the output of `tar` into `ssh` if you want:

```
tar czf - myfiles | ssh username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx \
        "cd /root/myfolder && tee myfile.tar.gz > myfile_2020-06-23.tar.gz"
```

Comment: `cat` usage is not always useless. Sometimes it just shows what you're doing cleaner. But great usage of `tee`.